# Find Iterative Method Convergence Rate

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

Given $f(x)\in C^2[a,b]$ s.t there is a point $x_0$ s.t $f(x_0)=0,f'(x_0)\ne 0 $,
and the iterative method is defined as follows :
$$ x_{k+1} = x_k - f(x_k)/g(x_k) ,\qquad g(x_k) = \frac{f(x_k +f(x_k))-f(x_k)}{f(x_k)} $$

I'd like to have some help with finding the convergence rate of the method above.
I'd be grateful if anyone could point me to the solution , thanks in advance.

Comment: I saw this somewhere. It is a derivative-free Newton method. I wonder if it is not Ostrawski's method.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici , thanks for the answer, I'd like to know if you can provide any explanation about the convergence rate of this method.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally got it for you . Have a look at [Steffensen's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steffensen%27s_method).

The $g(x)$ in your formula approximates the derivative of the function. This then makes a derivative-free Newton method. Same quadratic convergence as Newton.